# HttpContext(User.Identity) in Controller (asp web api) not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have some problems with correctly working `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`. From Controller constructor this doesn't work, I have to implement this to some method. Look at this example.

```
    public class SomeControler : ApiController
    {
        private UserData userData;
        
        // NOT WORKING
        public ChartsController(
            RegisteredUserData registeredUserData,
            NotLoggedInUserData NotLoggedInUserData
        {
            var isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            this.userData = isAuthenticated
                ? (IUserData)registeredUserData
                : (IUserData)NotLoggedInUserData;
        }
        
        // WORKING
        public SomeMethod(
            RegisteredUserData registeredUserData,
            NotLoggedInUserData NotLoggedInUserData
        {
            var isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            this.userData = isAuthenticated
                ? (IUserData)registeredUserData
                : (IUserData)NotLoggedInUserData;
        }
    }
```

How I can fix this? I spent a lot of time for answer in web but i didnt get this.

Regards.

#### edit

I found an answer. Is it good solution ?

```
 public class SomeControler : ApiController
{
    private RegisteredUserData registeredUserData;
    private NotLoggedInUserData notLoggedInUserData;
    private UserData userData 
    {
      get
      {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
          return registeredUserData;
        }
        return notLoggedInUserData;
      }
    }

    public ChartsController(
        RegisteredUserData registeredUserData,
        NotLoggedInUserData notLoggedInUserData
    {
       this.registeredUserData = registeredUserData;
       this.notLoggedInUserData = notLoggedInUserData;
    }

}
```

Comment: `// NOT WORKING` Give us more context. What do you mean by `// NOT WORKING`? What **explicitly** happens? Is an exception thrown? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, the request and `HttpContext` is not available yet in the construct of the controller because of where in the request flow the controller is initialized. You have to access it in an action where by then, the request and context would have been fully realized.

Next do not couple your controllers to `HttpContext`. It makes your code difficult to test and maintain.

Extract the desired information in a service abstraction.

```
public interface IUserDataAccessor {
    IUserData UserData { get; }
}

public class UserDataAccessor : IUserDataAccessor {
    private readonly RegisteredUserData registeredUserData;
    private readonly NotLoggedInUserData notLoggedInUserData;

    public UserDataAccessor(
        RegisteredUserData registeredUserData,
        NotLoggedInUserData notLoggedInUserData) {
        this.registeredUserData = registeredUserData;
        this.notLoggedInUserData = notLoggedInUserData;
    }    

    public IUserData UserData {
        get {
            if (HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated) {
                return registeredUserData;
            }
            return notLoggedInUserData;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the controller to remain lean with just the dependency on the abstraction.

```
public class ChartsController : ApiController {
    private readonly IUserDataAccessor accessor;

    public ChartsController(IUserDataAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult SomeAction() {
        var userData = accessor.UserData;
        //...do something associated with user data
        return OK();
    }
}
```

Finally make sure that the abstraction and it's implementation a registered with your dependency container in your composition root.

Comment: It will always be NotRegistered / Not authenticated inside constructor. Do you have any better solution to inject authenticated user to controller constructor ?

Comment: @TejasPatel I am not accessing the user in the constructor. I wont be available at that point as you already know. It will only be available in an action. I inject the accessor in the constructor and them get the user with the action itself.

Comment: Yes - Is there any way to inject authenticated user identity in constructor as I want to create Repository object and pass current user to it inside the constructor rather than in each action.

Comment: No. you are not understanding. Accessing the identity is only available with the context of an action. Not directly. so you can inject an accessor within you repository but you will call your repository members from within an action where the identity would have been set by then